# How to display dates and times in clients timezone

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

Suppose the server is located in USA (MST) and an user from Chennai (IST) is making a payment. Both the server and user are in different timezones. The MST (Mountain Standard Time) is 7 hours behind GMT (Greenwich Meridian Time) and the IST (Indian Standard Time) is 5.30 hours ahead of GMT, that is both the server and user have a time difference of 12:30 hours. If the user is making the payment on 9/20/2011 9:00 AM then the time at the server is 8/20/2011 8:30 PM. So which time you have to record in the database? If the application stores the user’s time in the database then if someone from US is seeing the transaction will likely see a wrong time i.e. 8/20/2011 8:30 PM. The other option is storing the server’s time in the database (that what we normally do), then the user will be unhappy seeing a wrong time.

Can you please help me. Much appriciated.

Comment: One good way (IMHO) to deal with this is to have the server in GMT time and have everyone sync to that timezone.  Then, there would be a conversion, but no one has to think about where they are, except where they are relative to GMT time (and each user of the DB would know that).

Answer (score 3):

I always use the **UTC time** to record everything, in any computer/server around the word.

[DateTime.UtcNow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Then when I show the date and time to some user, I just change it base on their local time zone.

Comment: But this doesn't handle day light saving, does it? Let's say a date time was converted to universal time from GMT+2, and now DST is over and time zone is GMT+1, wouldn't the same date show as a different value altogether?

Comment: we not convert it to UTC, UTC is the base datetime across all computers, and its the same for all... but you must take it as it is, not convert it

Answer (score 1):

On saving any dates convert it into **UTC** and save into database, fore eg;

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var Date = now.ToUniversalTime();
```

OR

```
var Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

and on displaying dates get the current Timezone of user and use it to convert the UTC date ,

```
 var _Timezone = // store timezone id here
 var southPole = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(_Timezone);
 DateTime userTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Date , southPole);
```

You can store the Timezone of different users in a database or get the current Timezone of the user logged in;

```
var _Timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

This method is not applicable in server side,

**NOTE**

You can get list of timezones from this code,

```
var timeZones = System.TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

foreach ( var timeZone in timeZones )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} - {1}", timeZone.Id,  timeZone.DisplayName );
}
```